# Linkedin invalid redirect_uri with ionic.io

Tags: ionic-framework, linkedin-api

I am trying to add Linkedin authentication with ionic.io following the [official tutorial](http://docs.ionic.io/v2.0.0-beta/docs/social-provider-linkedin). The tutorial doesn't mention the redirect_uri due to which I have left it as blank. But when I try to login using my Ionic app on android, an error occurs. What is the correct redirect_uri to use in ionic.io application. The linkedin error goes like this:

```
Invalid redirect_uri. The value must match a URL registered with the API key.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After running the app in debug mode, I finally figured out the redirect_url and its working fine. The redirect url is:

```
https://api.ionic.io/auth/integrations/linkedin
```